# initWithDocPath not found

Tags: iphone, warnings

it shows me warning that initWithDocPath not found when i want to get private directory content..

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)loadScaryBugDocs {
      NSString *documentsDirectory = [VideoDatabase getPrivateDocsDir];
 NSError *error;
 NSArray *files =[NSFileManagerdefaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
if (files == nil) {
    return nil;
}
NSMutableArray *retval = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:files.count];
for (NSString *file in files) {
    if ([file.pathExtension compare:@"scarybug" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        VideoNotepadViewController *doc = [[[VideoNotepadViewController alloc] initWithDocPath:fullPath] autorelease];
//shows warning here 
        [retval addObject:doc];
    }
}

return retval;

}
```

Comment: What class is `loadScaryBugDocs` part of?  Does your `VideoNotepadViewController` declare an `initWithDocPath:` method in its `@interface`?

Comment: loadScaryBugDocs is part of videoDatabase class and initWithDocPath is not declare in that class because i think its not needed cos its works fine without declare that method ....

Comment: Does `VideoNotepadViewController` actually have a method named `initWithDocPath:`?  Exactly what does the warning say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `initWithDocPath:` method in `VideoNotepadViewController`.  Apple doesn't provide a method by that name.

Comment: what is the return type of that method ??

Comment: You can set the return type to `id` or to `VideoNotepadViewController*`.